# Как правильно передать массив кортежей в метод через аннотацию, требующую callable?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Пытаюсь написать параметризованный тест, использую `itertools`, `unittest_data_provider`.

Есть два набора данных: `REQUESTS`, `LOCALES`. В каждом по несколько элементов.

```
REQUESTS = [
    {
        'name': 'string',
        'request': {'object': 'data'}
    }
]

LOCALES = [
    {
        'name': 'string',
        'json': {'object': 'data'},
        'pattern': 'string'
    }
]
```

Получаю его декартово произведение:

```
# Cartesian product of input iterables.  Equivalent to nested for-loops.
PRODUCT = itertools.product(REQUESTS, LOCALES)
```

Вывел поэлементно на печать. Как я и ожидаю, внутри находится кортеж (tuple), а в нем два элемента.

```
test = ({
           'request': {'object': 'data'},
           'name': 'string'
       },
       {
           'pattern': u'string',
           'json': {'object': 'data'},
           'name': 'string'
       })
```

Теперь есть тестовый метод, который должен получить эти данные. Сделал несколько попыток отдать ему данные. Первая, наивная. Хочу передать кортеж, а потом разобрать его внутри метода:

```
@data_provider(itertools.product(REQUESTS, LOCALE_SETS))
def test_locale(self, data):
```

> TypeError: 'itertools.product' object is not callable

Предположил, что требуется вызываемый метод, чтобы доставать элементы из массива:

```
@data_provider(itertools.product(REQUESTS, LOCALES).next)
def test_locale(self, data):
```

> TypeError: test_locale() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Видимо, оба элемента кортежа передаются как отдельные аргументы метода?

```
@data_provider(itertools.product(REQUESTS, LOCALES).next)
def test_locale(self, request_data, locale_data):
```

> TypeError: test_locale() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

**Что происходит? Я поменял только сигнатуру метода, но в него теперь передается ещё на один аргумент больше?**

Какими должны быть эти две строки, чтобы в каждый вызов метода передавался ровно один набор данных из декартового произведения двух массивов? Мне не важно, будет ли это один аргумент, два или пять.

---

Решил узнать, сколько всего передается аргументов:

```
@data_provider(itertools.product(REQUESTS, LOCALES).next)
def test_locale(self, *args):
    for i in args:
        print i
```

Результат:

```
request
name
pattern
json
name
```

Отлично, их пять! (похоже, происходит flatten кортежа) Пускай тогда и будет пять именованных аргументов:

```
@data_provider(itertools.product(REQUESTS, LOCALES).next)
def test_locale(self, request, request_name, locale_pattern, locale_json, locale_name):
```

> TypeError: test_locale() takes exactly 6 arguments (3 given)

**Почему их снова три?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, я неправильно понял требование передавать callable. Передаваемый декоратору объект будет вызываться не многократно (что предполагает использование `.next`), а однажды. **Поэтому правильным решением будет объявить лямбду:**

```
@data_provider(lambda: itertools.product(REQUESTS, LOCALES))
def test_locale(self, request_data, locale_data):
```

Теперь передается массив, внутри которого находятся кортежи, в каждом по два словаря. А раньше передавался один кортеж из этого массива.